# Creating an image collection from multiple uploaded images

Tags: google-earth-engine, image

Please help a noob to find a way (any way) to work with multiple (hundreds) images that I want to (upload and) process with earth engine. Here are the options I see:

1. Use interactive asset management tool to create an image collection. This involves hours of mouse clicking and dragging the files from a folder to a collection - not acceptable.
2. Cut and paste the list of files into a colab/python script to upload to GEE using earthengine command tool, then drag and drop them into a collection (as far as I can tell earthengine does not allow uploading files into a collection directly) - also unacceptable.
3. Use geebam. Looks like a great option, unfortunately, after days of trying, could not get it to work. I can delete assets with the tool, but when trying to upload, I am getting all sorts of errors. I think these are related to google cloud authentication but not sure.
4. I tried using ee.data.listAssets (and similar) to get a list of assets (images) that I uploaded to GEE using earthengine to build a collection. I am getting nowhere since the process involves calling getInfo() and it, apparently, cannot me mapped over a list.

This seems to me like a very basic problem and yet I cannot find any solutions (after days of searching). What am I missing? Is this by design, to make people pay? Well, I am ready to pay, but I do not see any options. This is ridiculous...

Answer (score 2):

From https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_upload:

> Give the image an appropriate asset ID (which doesn't already exist) in your user folder. **If you'd like to upload the image into an existing folder or collection, prefix the asset ID with the folder or collection ID, for example `/users/name/folder-or-collection-id/new-asset`.**

This will work with any method of uploading assets, not just the dialog.